# Destroy Android application

Tags: android

I have developed an application which is working fine.

In that i have used some static variables and also set Application level variables.
My problem is that even after setting finish() on each activity, application is showing in Running mode.

After closing the application, when i start the application after sometime, it will set the last changes.

How can i destroy my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked that application does not release the resources.
So, what i have done is :

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

It will kill the application.
It helps me a lot.

Comment: If you have to do this then you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: yeah.. you are right.. But i do not find out what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 12):

I think the correct answer is "you shouldn't".

It doesn't matter if your app is still running after the user stops using it.  Android will kill it when/if it needs to.

Your app most likely shouldn't even have an exit button.

Answer (score 3):

call

```
System.exit(0);
```

from within

```
OnDestroy()
```

And yes, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have called onDestroy for your activity.

Secondly, are you saving your preference some where else??

Comment: yes, i have called onDestroy as well as i have finished the activity.

Comment: onDestroy will destroy the activity not the application

Comment: I'm confused.  Should you *ever* call onDestroy()?  I thought it was called exclusively by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through these methods used for the destroying the activities

setResult() finish() and onActivityresult()

After calling setResult() call finish() for the activity that you want to finish & then in it's parent activity override onActivityResult() in this you can finished your application.

The solution given by oli is right android will destroy your application running. But I want add, only if it is lacking in system resources.

For more help please go through following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I suspect Nishant's problem is that he's storing data global to the application (perhaps in a static value in the Activity) and not in the activity instance.  This data will persist even after every instance of every activity has gone away, and will only be released after the system kills the entire process.

(I used to (wrongly) use this technique to persist a large dataset across orientation changes.)

The proper solution is to not do this.

Comment: Hey Edward, I have used this link to store values globally :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables.

I have some static int and string variables.